# How can I session destroy when user close the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

These codes work but when I click somewhere (link or button), redirected to logout.php

```
var s= 0;
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if (s == 0) {
        $.ajax({
                async: false,
        url: 'logout.php'
        });
    }
    s++;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable `s` and what is `sayac`?

Comment: There's no way to know if the page is being unloaded due to a page redirection or if the browser is being closed.

Comment: sorry, it is not sayac it's s

Comment: you could unset the session using `unset($_SESSION['key']);`

Answer (score 0):

You could put in your session a variable with time() inside and use it as a short expiry limit, and while the user is inside your page do continous ajax calls to a php that updates the expiry. At the top of your page put:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['expiry']))
    if(time() > $_SESSION['expiry']){
        session_destroy();
        header("Refresh:0");
        die();
    }
$_SESSION['expiry'] = time()+20;
```

keep_alive.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['expiry'] = time()+20;
```

And in your js ping keep_alive.php with ajax every 10 seconds. If the user closes the page and doesen't rapidly reopen it loses his session